# Bypass parameter prompt with Crystal Report 2008 server with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a very specific problem, and a work around solution will not help. I need to use my Crystal reporting server to generate the PDFs for a long list of reports.

I have used sample code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227542(VS.90).aspx to create a test report and this works perfectly.

I then created a report that outputs the parameter onto the page to start testing for parameter input. This works too.

Now I need to programmatically set the parameters, and then suppress the parameter input screen generated by the report viewer control.

I am able to set the parameter but the viewer control still prompts for parameter input. If I set the control to hide the parameter prompt I get the following error:

**Unable to get SI_MACHINECHOICE property value**

Here is my source code with the server name and credentials omitted.

Things I have tried:

- Setting the report name to the report and to an empty string.
- Changing the order of the ReportSource "setter" to before and after the parameters "setter".
- Using and not using the ShowFirstPage() method

I am using Crystal reports 12 dlls and the server is running off version 12 also. This is running on VS2008.

```
        string reportName = "TestReport2";



        //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227542(VS.90).aspx
        string serverName = "server";
        SessionMgr sessionMgr = new SessionMgr();
        EnterpriseSession enterpriseSession = sessionMgr.Logon("Administrator", "", serverName, "secEnterprise");
        EnterpriseService enterpriseService = enterpriseSession.GetService("InfoStore");
        InfoStore infoStore = new InfoStore(enterpriseService);
        enterpriseService = enterpriseSession.GetService("PSReportFactory");
        Object psrfObject = enterpriseService.Interface;
        PSReportFactory psReportFactory = (PSReportFactory)psrfObject;
        string queryString = "Select SI_ID, SI_NAME, SI_PARENTID From CI_INFOOBJECTS "
        + "Where SI_PROGID='CrystalEnterprise.Report' "
        + "And SI_NAME Like '" + reportName + "'";
        InfoObjects infoObjects = infoStore.Query(queryString);
        InfoObject infoObject = infoObjects[1];           

        ReportSource reportSource = psReportFactory.OpenReportSource(infoObject.ID);


        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportSource;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo.Clear();

        ParameterFields paramFields;
        paramFields = new ParameterFields();

        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue;
        paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        paramDiscreteValue.Value = "John Doe";

        ParameterField paramField;
        paramField = new ParameterField();
        paramField.Name = "UserName";
        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
        paramField.HasCurrentValue = true;
        paramField.ReportName = "";
        paramFields.Add(paramField);

        CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ShowFirstPage();
```

Comment: I just made a minor breakthrough. I will see if I can get it working for multiple parameters

Comment: Instead of setting up your parameters as Parameters in Crystal, how about setting up a "parameter table" in your datasource and feed that into Crystal? When you want to change parameters, you can edit your parameter table with standard SQL.  This way, Crystal can't pop up any parameter requests since, as far it knows, there are no parameters.

Comment: Hi, it has been a while since I saw this topic. I am not sure if you can manipulate the report when it is loaded onto a business objects server. When we use our local service (uses Crystal dlls) then one can edit the reports and we do it as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I resolved this issue.

This line ((ParameterFields)Session[reportGuid];) is my method of passing a sql dataset driven list of parameters to the code.

After this section of code I have some more that get a PDF off the server and displays that. If you use the normal Crystal report viewer it will re-run the report on every page changed event.

If you have problems with this kind of stuff, you can send me a message, and I can provide more code - this stuff is painful!

```
            string reportName = Request["RptName"].ToString();
            string reportGuid = Request["RptGuid"].ToString();
            string outputType = Request["outputType"].ToString();

            SessionMgr sessionMgr = new SessionMgr();
            EnterpriseSession enterpriseSession;
            EnterpriseService enterpriseService;
            InfoStore infoStore;
            InfoObjects infoObjects;
            InfoObject infoObject;
            ReportAppFactory reportAppFactory;
            ISCDReportClientDocument reportClientDocument;

            // Log on to the Enterprise service.
            // 
            enterpriseSession = sessionMgr.Logon(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessObjectsUser"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessObjectsPassword"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessObjectsServer"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BusinessObjectsAuthentication"].ToString());

            // Create an instance of the InfoStore Enterprise Service.
            enterpriseService = enterpriseSession.GetService("InfoStore");
            infoStore = new InfoStore(enterpriseService);

            // Query for the ID of the report in the Enterprise CMS.
            infoObjects = infoStore.Query("Select SI_ID From CI_INFOOBJECTS Where SI_NAME='" + reportName + "' And SI_INSTANCE=0");
            infoObject = infoObjects[1];

            // Create an instance of ReportAppFactory from the enterpriseSession.
            EnterpriseService tempService = enterpriseSession.GetService("", "RASReportFactory");
            reportAppFactory = (ReportAppFactory)tempService.Interface;

            ParameterFields paramFieldsDatabase = (ParameterFields)Session[reportGuid];

            // Use the OpenDocument() method of ReportClientDocument with the sample report ID passed in as a parameter.
            reportClientDocument = reportAppFactory.OpenDocument(infoObject.ID, 0);



            foreach (ParameterField paramFieldCrystal in paramFieldsDatabase)
            {
                try
                {

                    LabelInformation.Text = String.Format("{0} \n {1}", LabelInformation.Text, paramFieldCrystal.Name);

                    ParameterDiscreteValue val = (ParameterDiscreteValue)paramFieldCrystal.CurrentValues[0];
                    reportClientDocument.DataDefController.ParameterFieldController.SetCurrentValue("", paramFieldCrystal.Name, val.Value);


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errorList = String.Format("{0} \n {1}", errorList, ex.Message);
                }


            }
```